# What will be the cron expression for every 2 hour on cronos? I am using 0 */2 * * * but its not working

Tags: asp.net-core

I am using 0 */2 * * * cron expression for every 2 hours but its not working. I am using cronos for cron job. So what will be the cron expression for every 2 hour on cronos?

Comment: hello @BCMS RBL .. kindly provide your code snippet as we can support you

Comment: i think that '0 */2 * * *' is the correct expression for every 2 hours.  https://crontab.guru/every-2-hours.  as mentioned by @HanyHabib, perhaps there is an issue with the code.